# bq from gcloud SDK do not work in a virtual environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Running bq inside of of a python virtual environment in Ubuntu leads to the following `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/google-cloud-sdk/157/platform/bq/bq.py", line 60, in <module>
    import oauth2client_4_0.service_account
  File "/snap/google-cloud-sdk/157/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client_4_0/service_account.py", line 27, in <module>
  from oauth2client_4_0 import crypt
  File "/snap/google-cloud-sdk/157/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client_4_0/crypt.py", line 24, in <module>
  from oauth2client_4_0 import _pure_python_crypt
  File "/snap/google-cloud-sdk/157/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client_4_0/_pure_python_crypt.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pyasn1_modules.rfc2459 import Certificate
  File "/snap/google-cloud-sdk/157/platform/bq/third_party/pyasn1_modules/rfc2459.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pyasn1.type import opentype
  ImportError: cannot import name 'opentype'
```

This can be easily reproduced on a fresh GCE, and also on a local system where gcloud installed is installed.

```
~ lsb_release --al
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
~ python --version
Python 3.8.5
~ python3 -m venv .venv 
~ source ./.venv/bin/activate
~ bq version
```

Installing packages `pyasm1` and `pyasm1-modules` in this `venv` doesn't help, also tried several different version of these packages.

BTW:  The `bq` command works as expected without the `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it seems that there is an issue with Ubuntu systems that's causing this issue. I have made tests with many versions and these are the results:

```
ubuntu 20.04 python 3.8 --> no
ubuntu 20.04 python 3.7 --> no
ubuntu 18.04 python 3.6 --> no
debain 10 python 3.7 --> works
debian 10 python 3.8 --> works
```

I suggest at the time being using other OS like debian. There is an already create issue for this which you can [find here](https://issuetracker.google.com/172639037)